# pipenv: how to upgrade a single Python package?

Tags: python, pipenv-install

urllib3 version from Pipfile.lock: `"version": "==1.25.11"`

Due to a [security problem](https://cve.mitre.org/cgi-bin/cvename.cgi?name=CVE-2021-33503) I want to update urllib3 to `">=1.26.5"`

As this comes with Python, and we can't upgrade python right now I wanted to bump it separately. I'm fairly new to Python.

What I tried:

```
pipenv install urllib3~=1.26.5
```

What I got:

```
Resolving dependencies... ✘ Locking Failed! Warning: Your dependencies could not be resolved. You likely have a mismatch in your sub-dependencies.
```

Is it not possible to ugrade urllib3 without bumping my Python version? If it is possible, what am I doing wrong? I also checked pipenv was up to date.

Project python version: `3.7.9`

Comment: `pipenv update`?

Comment: pipenv update ran successfully, but did not update urllib3 to the version needed. I even tried removing it from the lockfile, then running pipenv update, but it just goes back to  1.25.11

Comment: You seem to have a library that explicitly requires a `urllib3` version other then 1.26.5. Of you find it there might be a chance that it can be upgraded as well.

Comment: Hi Klaus, I don't think it's a library requirement, it's just a security vulnerability in the old version that I would like to avoid as per the link above

Answer (score 1):

I had same problem, I just update my `requests` version in pipfile from

```
requests = "==2.22.0"
```

to

```
requests = "==2.27.1"
```

because usually `urllib3` is a dependency of `requests` it should solve the problem.

If it didn't solve the problem you could use `pipenv graph` to find the dependency that depends on `<1.26.5`